# how pass observable value to another page

Tags: angular, ionic4

hi i want compared value in page one and show the result in page two
i use this way but i can't see result
this .ts for page one

```
    items$: Observable<Item[]>;


constructor(public afs: AngularFirestore,public router:Router){
     this.items$ = Observable.combineLatest(
        this.type_place$,
      ).switchMap(([type_place]) => 
      afs.collection<Item>('restaurants', ref => {
          let query : firebase.firestore.Query = ref;
          if (type_place) { query = query.where('type_place', '==', type_place) };
          return query;
        }).valueChanges()
      );
}
open(){
  let navigationExtras: NavigationExtras = {
    queryParams: {
      special: JSON.stringify(this.items$)
    }
  };
  this.router.navigate(['resshow'], navigationExtras);
}
```

this ts. to page two

```
 if (params && params.special) {
      this.items$ = JSON.parse(params.special);

    }
```

this html to page two

```
  <div *ngIf="items$ | async; let items; else loading">
    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let item of items">
         {{item.name}}


      </li>
    </ul>
    <div *ngIf="items.length === 0">nothing</div>

  </div>
  <ng-template #loading>loading&hellip;</ng-template> 

</ion-list>
```

Comment: Can you share the snippet how you're accessing the *params* in 2nd ts file.

Comment: this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
        if (params && params.special) {
          this.data = JSON.parse(params.special);}